# Iterate through folder and return full file path

Tags: ruby

I wrote this code:

```
verz = 'C:\Users\GerdPC\Desktop\mouth'

Dir.foreach(verz) do |f|
 next if f == '.' or f == '..' 
 puts f
end
```

My problem is that I don't know how to return not only the filename `f` for eg:

```
sumba.png
```

But:

```
C:\Users\GerdPC\Desktop\mouth\sumba.png
```

So I tried:

```
 puts File.expand_path(f)
```

But this only expands the filename with the directory in which my program is running! What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this enough?

`puts "#{verz}\\#{f}"`

Comment: Thanks i had problems with `puts "#{verz}\#{f}"` and i didnt know that when i use it twice it works!

Comment: \ is a special character, so you need to escape it using \. Hence the double slash.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as below using [*`File::realdirpath`*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-realdirpath):

```
Dir.pwd # => "/home/kirti/Ruby"

Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd) do |file|
  puts File.realdirpath(file) unless ['.','..'].include? file
end

# >> /home/kirti/Ruby/tut.html
# >> /home/kirti/Ruby/test
#.........
#.........
```